# Reaction of nitro compounds with strong alkali?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, nitro-compounds

Why does a primary and a secondary nitro compound behave as an acid in the presence of strong alkali whereas tertiary nitro compounds do not?
Can anyone explain it with reactions?

Comment: How many $\alpha$ hydrogens are there on a tertiary nitro compound?

Comment: there is no alpha hydrogen in tertiary nitro compound

Comment: There is your answer then.

Answer (score 2):

In order for a compound to act as an acid, it must have a proton which can be abstracted. As you correctly pointed out, tertiary nitro compounds have no $\alpha$ hydrogens and therefore they cannot be deprotonated at the $\alpha$ position.

Of course, they could be deprotonated elsewhere, but if the other groups are just alkyl groups then this isn't really feasible as they have such a high $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Organic nitro compounds can tautomerise to give its aci-nitro form. As we know tautomers exist in a dynamic equilibrium, the enol form of nitro compound is called its aci-nitro form, which is present in a small amount in the equilibrium mixture. Aci-nitro form is the acidic form of a respective nitro compound, which is able to liberate an acidic hydrogen when needed.

Thus, when an alkali metal is added to a nitro compound, they react with the remaining aci-nitro form (which gets used up) and thus the equilibrium shifts right, producing more aci-nitro compounds. This results in complete dissolution of the alkali in the nitro compound, provided that the given amount of nitro compounds is able to synthesise required amount of aci-nitro form to completely dissolve the alkali.

The role of alpha hydrogen in the nitro compound is to take part in tautomerisation:

[image: Keto-enol tautomerism of nitro compound]

Comment: Please edit your post for grammar, punctuation, and style; use MathJax for typesetting; and avoid ethereal links.